# The Error Response Data Retrieval from Server

Tags: ios10, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

The basic functions of connection.

```
+ (NSMutableURLRequest*)downloadUrl:(NSString*)baseURL Myurl: (NSString*)myurl Params:(NSString*)params{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self mobileURL], myurl]];
    if([baseURL isEqualToString:@"web"]){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self webURL], myurl]];
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *conn= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [conn setTimeoutInterval:60];
    if(![params isEqualToString:@""]){
        [conn setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [conn setValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
        [conn setValue:@"charset" forHTTPHeaderField:@"utf-8"];
        [conn setValue:@"Content-Length" forHTTPHeaderField:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)params.length]];
        [conn setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
        [conn setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
        conn.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return conn;
}
```

To post the data to server

```
- (void)GetUserBriefcase:(NSString*)baseURL Myurl: (NSString*)myurl Params:(NSString*)params{
    NSLog(@"lagi loading");
    params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user-id=%@", kinerjaDBData[1]];
   // [Base killNSURLSessionDataTask:getUserBriefcaseDataTask];
    getUserBriefcaseDataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:[Base downloadUrl:baseURL Myurl:myurl Params:params]
                                                                  completionHandler:
                                   ^(NSData*data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                       if(!error){
                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                               NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                               if([((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode] == 404){
                                                   //response return using it --> [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) URL]
                                                   result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) URL]];
                                               }
                                               if([result containsString:@"www.test.com"] || [result containsString:@"SSL"]){
                                               }else{//manage result and used
                                                   [self viewUserBriefcase:result];
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                   }];
    [getUserBriefcaseDataTask resume];
}
```

I am using Objective-C in application development in Xcode. I perform such a connection, or rather data collection to the server and I made a CollectionView to display the data set and create a refresh button to reload the data back to me. But after four times reloading data, I get this error:

The error response data retrieval from server.

```
[] nw_route_get_ifindex socket(PF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, PF_ROUTE) failed: [24] Too many open files, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000114d87682 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000114d7c7d1 nw_route_get_ifindex + 774
    2   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000114d941a1 nw_path_simulator_get_path_result + 263
    3   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000114d93eb0 nw_path_create_evaluator_for_endpoint + 289
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000116273de1 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 415
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b04980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b2e0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b0be6b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b0cb9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b0f3b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b0f08b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114edd736 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114edd211 start_wqthread + 13
2016-11-19 10:58:23.311959 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceCreateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.321131 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.333921 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.345676 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.353850 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.376302 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.390109 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.401419 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.420026 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67402] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.430306 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.440195 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67402] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.446406 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67402] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.449601 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67402] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.460080 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67402] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.470784 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.477568 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.488624 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.492833 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.501657 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.504637 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.513821 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.517457 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.530043 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.534482 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.545627 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.549564 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.563504 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67520] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.567585 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67520] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.578143 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.582635 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.598188 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.603237 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67392] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.622190 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67520] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.637931 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.648533 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.655368 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.668714 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.675478 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.688955 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.763394 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.798062 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.806722 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.829096 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.838123 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.860140 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.869975 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.897130 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.910146 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.923213 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.927595 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.937690 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.942660 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.956083 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.961562 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:23.999130 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.006431 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.017556 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.024247 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67072] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.052014 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.059502 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.080482 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.087611 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.107065 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.112379 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.123932 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.129982 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.144713 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.152216 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.165983 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.172315 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.183510 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.188550 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.200391 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.208927 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
2016-11-19 10:58:24.222276 Kinerjapay-Android_v3-ios_v1[2194:67389] []
```

Is my data retrieval wrong way?
Or is there another problem?